# Access to protected method

Tags: java

**Ex15.java**

```
import utils.A;

public class Ex15  extends A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
        a.print("Test");
    }
}

**utils/A.java**

package utils;

public class A {
    public A(){
        System.out.println("A created");
    }

    protected void print(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**tree**

```
michael@michael:~/Downloads/thinking_in_java/Reusing_Classes/Ex15$ tree
.
├── Ex15.class
├── Ex15.java
└── utils
    ├── A.class
    └── A.java
```

**Compilation:**

```
michael@michael:~/Downloads/thinking_in_java/Reusing_Classes/Ex15$ javac Ex15.java
Ex15.java:6: error: print(String) has protected access in A
        a.print("Test");
         ^
1 error
```

**Documentation**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1

Quotation:

> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is
>   permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> A subclass S is regarded as being responsible for the implementation
>   of objects of class C. Depending on C's accessibility, S may be
>   declared in the same package as C, or in different package of the same
>   module as C, or in a package of a different module entirely.

**Problem**

Class Ex15 is a subclass of A. It is in a different package (in a default one, but definitely not in "utils").  Access to the protected method is within the body of the subclass. I didn't expect a compilation error.

Could you clarify why this error occurs and how to make the code compile.

Comment: static methods are not part of a object, they are only defined in classes.

Comment: You should separate your driver from your Example classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to invoke a method with a scope that you cannot see from that point. Even if your class is a subclass, it cannot access the method because it's not in its visibility. You can invoke private/protected method of the class Ext15, not the class A. A is still in another package.

Try to look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're calling at `a.print("Text")` not as a subclass. When you're creating a superclass like that it's like creating it any other class that is not a subclass.

`protected` you can access as the subclass like `super.print("Text")`.